# How do I retrieve the response cookies through curlpp?

Tags: c++, curlpp

how can I retrieve the response cookies from a curlpp request?

I want to store the PHP session off of a HTTP GET request. This is my current code:

```
void Grooveshark::Connection::processPHPCookie()
{
    std::ostringstream buffer;

    gsDebug("Processing PHP cookie...");

    try {
        request.setOpt<cURLpp::Options::Url>("http://listen.grooveshark.com");
        request.setOpt<cURLpp::Options::WriteStream>(&buffer);
        request.perform();

        // Get the PHP Session cookie here..

    } catch (cURLpp::LogicError& exception) {
        gsError(exception.what());
    } catch (cURLpp::RuntimeError& exception) {
        gsError(exception.what());
    }

    gsDebug("Processing complete...");
}
```

`request` is a `cURLpp::Easy` instance. If you need more details you can find my source code [here](https://github.com/mkroman/quirk/blob/master/src/Grooveshark/Connection.cpp#L45)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, set `exEasy.setOpt(curlpp::options::CookieFile("")`
then call `exEasy.perform()`,
then loop through

```
std::list<std::string> cookies;
curlpp::infos::CookieList::get(exEasy, cookies);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://bitbucket.org/moriarty/curlpp/src/ac658073c87a/examples/example07.cpp

That example seems to have what you want. In particular this code:

```cpp
std::cout << "\nCookies from cookie engine:" << std::endl;
std::list<std::string> cookies;
curlpp::infos::CookieList::get(exEasy, cookies);
int i = 1;
for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator it = cookies.begin(); it != cookies.end(); ++it, i++)
{
    std::cout << "[" << i << "]: " << MakeCookie(*it) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that MakeCookie returns a struct called MyCookie inside the example, so you would also need:

```
struct MyCookie
{
        std::string name;
        std::string value;
        std::string domain;
        std::string path;
        time_t expires;
        bool tail;
        bool secure;
};

MyCookie
MakeCookie(const std::string &str_cookie)
{
        std::vector<std::string> vC = splitCookieStr(str_cookie);
        MyCookie cook;

        cook.domain = vC[0];
        cook.tail = vC[1] == "TRUE";
        cook.path = vC[2];
        cook.secure = vC[3] == "TRUE";
        cook.expires = StrToInt(vC[4]);
        cook.name = vC[5];
        cook.value = vC[6];

        return cook;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the link now: https://github.com/datacratic/curlpp/blob/master/examples/example07.cpp

Comment: I've tried this right now and it's not working, despite I've put the verbose to true and it shows a "Set-Cookie" header in the response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers link is now located at: https://github.com/datacratic/curlpp/blob/master/examples/example07.cpp

It should be noted that if one wants to just get cookie responses then on must pass an empty string to the cookie lists.

For the previous example `exEasy.setOpt(new curlpp::options::CookieList(""))` would need to be added in order to get cookie strings (something other than an empty string might be used but I was not able to find further documentation).